# updating old NPAPI plugin for Maya 2014

Tags: npapi, maya

I need some advice on how to update an external web browser plugin for Maya 2014 on windows 7.  The plugin was last updated in 2008 and works perfectly in an older browser like Firefox 3.  However, any later browser (Firefox 3.5 to 26) immediately breaks the plugin.

The error I am getting in firebug is: 
`Error: Error calling method on NPObject! return MWTObject.execute(CommandText)`

I am a complete novice at API programming and am in way over my head on this one.  I think the error is being caused by NPP_GetValue getting called 2 times and the plugin not being able to hanlde it. The main.cpp is as follows:

```
//-
// ==========================================================================
// Copyright 1995,2006,2008 Autodesk, Inc. All rights reserved.
//
// Use of this software is subject to the terms of the Autodesk
// license agreement provided at the time of installation or download,
// or which otherwise accompanies this software in either electronic
// or hard copy form.
// ==========================================================================
//+

#include "mcp.h"
#include "PluginObject.h"

NPNetscapeFuncs *browser;
NPNetscapeFuncs NPNFuncs;

NPError     NPP_New(NPMIMEType pluginType, NPP instance, uint16 mode, int16 argc, char* argn[], char* argv[], NPSavedData* saved);
NPError     NPP_Destroy(NPP instance, NPSavedData** save);
NPError     NPP_SetWindow(NPP instance, NPWindow* window);
NPError     NPP_NewStream(NPP instance, NPMIMEType type, NPStream* stream, NPBool seekable, uint16* stype);
NPError     NPP_DestroyStream(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, NPReason reason);
int32       NPP_WriteReady(NPP instance, NPStream* stream);
int32       NPP_Write(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, int32 offset, int32 len, void* buffer);
void        NPP_StreamAsFile(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, const char* fname);
void        NPP_Print(NPP instance, NPPrint* platformPrint);
int16       NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance, void* event);
void        NPP_URLNotify(NPP instance, const char* URL, NPReason reason, void* notifyData);
NPError     NPP_GetValue(NPP instance, NPPVariable variable, void *value);
NPError     NPP_SetValue(NPP instance, NPNVariable variable, void *value);

char *NPP_GetMIMEDescription(void) {
    return "application/x-mcp::MCP Plugin";
}

NPError OSCALL NP_Initialize(NPNetscapeFuncs* pFuncs)
{
  if(pFuncs == NULL)
    return NPERR_INVALID_FUNCTABLE_ERROR;

  if(HIBYTE(pFuncs->version) > NP_VERSION_MAJOR)
    return NPERR_INCOMPATIBLE_VERSION_ERROR;

  if(pFuncs->size < sizeof(NPNetscapeFuncs))
    return NPERR_INVALID_FUNCTABLE_ERROR;

  NPNFuncs.size                    = pFuncs->size;
  NPNFuncs.version                 = pFuncs->version;
  NPNFuncs.geturlnotify            = pFuncs->geturlnotify;
  NPNFuncs.geturl                  = pFuncs->geturl;
  NPNFuncs.posturlnotify           = pFuncs->posturlnotify;
  NPNFuncs.posturl                 = pFuncs->posturl;
  NPNFuncs.requestread             = pFuncs->requestread;
  NPNFuncs.newstream               = pFuncs->newstream;
  NPNFuncs.write                   = pFuncs->write;
  NPNFuncs.destroystream           = pFuncs->destroystream;
  NPNFuncs.status                  = pFuncs->status;
  NPNFuncs.uagent                  = pFuncs->uagent;
  NPNFuncs.memalloc                = pFuncs->memalloc;
  NPNFuncs.memfree                 = pFuncs->memfree;
  NPNFuncs.memflush                = pFuncs->memflush;
  NPNFuncs.reloadplugins           = pFuncs->reloadplugins;
  NPNFuncs.getJavaEnv              = pFuncs->getJavaEnv;
  NPNFuncs.getJavaPeer             = pFuncs->getJavaPeer;
  NPNFuncs.getvalue                = pFuncs->getvalue;
  NPNFuncs.setvalue                = pFuncs->setvalue;
  NPNFuncs.invalidaterect          = pFuncs->invalidaterect;
  NPNFuncs.invalidateregion        = pFuncs->invalidateregion;
  NPNFuncs.forceredraw             = pFuncs->forceredraw;
  NPNFuncs.getstringidentifier     = pFuncs->getstringidentifier;
  NPNFuncs.getstringidentifiers    = pFuncs->getstringidentifiers;
  NPNFuncs.getintidentifier        = pFuncs->getintidentifier;
  NPNFuncs.identifierisstring      = pFuncs->identifierisstring;
  NPNFuncs.utf8fromidentifier      = pFuncs->utf8fromidentifier;
  NPNFuncs.intfromidentifier       = pFuncs->intfromidentifier;
  NPNFuncs.createobject            = pFuncs->createobject;
  NPNFuncs.retainobject            = pFuncs->retainobject;
  NPNFuncs.releaseobject           = pFuncs->releaseobject;
  NPNFuncs.invoke                  = pFuncs->invoke;
  NPNFuncs.invokeDefault           = pFuncs->invokeDefault;
  NPNFuncs.evaluate                = pFuncs->evaluate;
  NPNFuncs.getproperty             = pFuncs->getproperty;
  NPNFuncs.setproperty             = pFuncs->setproperty;
  NPNFuncs.removeproperty          = pFuncs->removeproperty;
  NPNFuncs.hasproperty             = pFuncs->hasproperty;
  NPNFuncs.hasmethod               = pFuncs->hasmethod;
  NPNFuncs.releasevariantvalue     = pFuncs->releasevariantvalue;
  NPNFuncs.setexception            = pFuncs->setexception;

  browser = &NPNFuncs;

  return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError OSCALL NP_GetEntryPoints(NPPluginFuncs* pluginFuncs)
{
  if(pluginFuncs == NULL)
    return NPERR_INVALID_FUNCTABLE_ERROR;

  if(pluginFuncs->size < sizeof(NPPluginFuncs))
    return NPERR_INVALID_FUNCTABLE_ERROR;

    pluginFuncs->version = (NP_VERSION_MAJOR << 8) | NP_VERSION_MINOR;
    pluginFuncs->size = sizeof(NPPluginFuncs);
    pluginFuncs->newp = NPP_New;
    pluginFuncs->destroy = NPP_Destroy;
    pluginFuncs->setwindow = NPP_SetWindow;
    pluginFuncs->newstream = NPP_NewStream;
    pluginFuncs->destroystream = NPP_DestroyStream;
    pluginFuncs->asfile = NPP_StreamAsFile;
    pluginFuncs->writeready = NPP_WriteReady;
    pluginFuncs->write = NPP_Write;
    pluginFuncs->print = NPP_Print;
    pluginFuncs->event = NPP_HandleEvent;
    pluginFuncs->urlnotify = NPP_URLNotify;
    pluginFuncs->getvalue = NPP_GetValue;
    pluginFuncs->setvalue = NPP_SetValue;
    pluginFuncs->javaClass     = NULL;

    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError OSCALL NP_Shutdown(void)
{
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPP_New(NPMIMEType pluginType, NPP instance, uint16 mode, int16 argc, char* argn[], char* argv[], NPSavedData* saved)
{
    if (browser->version >= 14)
        instance->pdata = browser->createobject (instance, getPluginClass());

    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPP_Destroy(NPP instance, NPSavedData** save)
{
    PluginObject *obj = (PluginObject *)instance->pdata;

    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPP_SetWindow(NPP instance, NPWindow* window)
{
    PluginObject *obj = (PluginObject *)instance->pdata;

    // Do nothing if browser didn't support NPN_CreateObject which would have created the PluginObject.
    if (obj != NULL) {
        obj->window = window;
    }
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}


NPError NPP_NewStream(NPP instance, NPMIMEType type, NPStream* stream, NPBool seekable, uint16* stype)
{
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

NPError NPP_DestroyStream(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, NPReason reason)
{
    return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
}

int32 NPP_WriteReady(NPP instance, NPStream* stream)
{
    return 0;
}

int32 NPP_Write(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, int32 offset, int32 len, void* buffer)
{
    return 0;
}

void NPP_StreamAsFile(NPP instance, NPStream* stream, const char* fname)
{

}

void NPP_Print(NPP instance, NPPrint* platformPrint)
{

}

int16 NPP_HandleEvent(NPP instance, void* event)
{
    return 0;
}

void NPP_URLNotify(NPP instance, const char* url, NPReason reason, void* notifyData)
{

}

NPError NPP_GetValue(NPP instance, NPPVariable variable, void *value)
{
  if(instance == NULL)
    return NPERR_INVALID_INSTANCE_ERROR;

  if (variable == NPPVpluginScriptableNPObject) {
        void **v = (void **)value;
        PluginObject *obj = (PluginObject *)instance->pdata;
        // Increase reference count
        obj->referenceCount++;
        *v = obj;
        return NPERR_NO_ERROR;
    }
    return NPERR_GENERIC_ERROR;
}

NPError NPP_SetValue(NPP instance, NPNVariable variable, void *value)
{
    return NPERR_GENERIC_ERROR;
}
```

I don't know if this is enough information to even diagnose the problem, but any help would be much appreciated.  If anyone wants to look at the full source code for this plugin it is available in your Maya install directory (if you have Maya, of course) in devkit/externalwebbrowser/windows

Comment: Elaborate on *"the error"*.

Comment: The error I am getting in firebug is: Error: Error calling method on NPObject!
 

return MWTObject.execute(CommandText)

Comment: That error is important to the question so please appropriately mention it by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Added to the original post - thanks for the info.

Comment: Good. And use the backticks (`) to encompass the error message.

Comment: Even that error message isn't all that useful; you need to attach a debugger to different entrypoints and see if you can figure out where you get and where you don't.  You might want to look at FireBreath (firebreath.org)

Comment: You should also mention what platform(s) you are testing with. Different OSes have different requirements for NPAPI (e.g., if you are testing on Mac, maybe the issue is not negotiating modern drawing and event models).